# Barra de rolagem não oculta no Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, html5, internet-explorer

Estou criando um site onde utilizo vários elementos `div` do tamanho da página, e links no menu superior que direciona para essas `div`, fazendo um efeito de rolagem de página a cada clique.

O meu problema é que no Internet Explorer, a barra de rolagem não some, mesmo que eu utilize `overflow:hidden` no , `body` ou `div` principal.

**[EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/leandroluk/Zk5g3/2/)**

**Notas:** Não sei porque mas no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leandroluk/Zk5g3/2/) o código não funcionou 100%.

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir o problema que você descreve, dá para pôr uma imagem aqui também? Em relação ao jsfiddle, a versão 1.10 do jQuery tem problemas no jsfiddle, eu mudei também para `no wrap` para a funcção `switchPage` não estar fora de escopo/scope: http://jsfiddle.net/Zk5g3/3/

Comment: Como referido pelo @Sergio, o problema não está perceptível o suficiente para receber respostas assertivas. Uma captura de tela na própria pergunta vai permite que os utilizadores visualizem correctamente o problema. É sempre bom também adicionar na pergunta o código mínimo necessário à reprodução do problema.

Comment: segue a tela: http://imageshack.com/a/img833/2678/1tqg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, o fato é que quando eu tinha testado o `overflow` nos elementos, acabei não testando o mesmo para a tag `html`.

Quando inseri a declaração `overflow:hidden` na tag `html`, o problema foi solucionado:

```css
html{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tente utilizar:

```css
#div {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

ou então:

```javascript
$("#div").css("overflow","hidden");
```

Talvez o jQuery consiga fazer funcionar no IE. Se a `div` estiver tomando toda a tela, tente fazer alguns pixels menor.

**Edit**: Pode ser desta forma também:

```css
* {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: em todos os navegadores está funcionando normalmente, o detalhe é que o scrollbox de baixo não quer ocultar. vou tentar com essas soluções, quem sabe...

Answer (score 2):

Quando tive este problema no IE fiz da seguinte maneira:

```css
.divOverflowHidden{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.divFilhos {
  position: absolute;
}
```

funcionou para mim, não tenho mais esse link mais era do SO em inglês .

Comment: Você poderia incluir uma explicação?